# Powershell Get-ChildItem command

Tags: powershell, filelist

I use the Windows Command Line to export a list of all files in a directory, including the full path. the command is:

```
DIR /b/s/n/a:-d/o:>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\file_list.txt"    
/b to list only files and folder with no additional information;
/s to list all files within the subfolders;    
/n to list long names (here is my problem, it still list max. 255 char);    
/a:-d to not list directories without files;    
/o to sort files.
```

I would like to run a similar command on PowerShell but to list files with over 255 characters.

Can anyone help on the command?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet with the `-recurse` switch to
   retrieve all files and folder from a specific path.
2. Use [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) to exclude all empty Directories
   (`$_.PSIsContainer` equals true and file count greater zero).
3. Use [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) to select the `FullName` of the items.
4. Use the [Out-File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113363) cmdlet to store the result in a file.

**Example:**

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ -recurse | 
    Where-Object {(($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -or (($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and ($_.GetFiles().Count -gt 0)))} | 
     Select-Object FullName | 
     Out-File 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file_list.txt'
```